# "Incorrect syntax near 'RETURNS'. Expecting AS, FOR, or WITH." (SQL User Defined Function)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please review the SQL code below for a user-defined function I am trying to create.  In SSMS, there seems to be an issue with this part of the code:

```
 RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
```

I am getting the error message:

> Incorrect syntax near 'RETURNS'. Expecting AS, FOR, or WITH.

SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[udfGetKillContractTreatmentMostSevere] 
    (@paramContractCode NUMBER(5,0))
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    --Return the value into this variable
    DECLARE @GetMostSevereTreatement VARCHAR(50)

    --Severity Table stores the logic for evaluating the severity of the medice
    DECLARE @lkpTreatmentSeverity AS TABLE (MedicineType VARCHAR(2), Severity INT)

    INSERT INTO @lkpTreatmentSeverity 
    VALUES (NULL, 0), ('NAE', 1), ('NAIHM', 2), ('CONVEN', 3), ('UNKNOWN', 4)

    --Query to return the most severe medicine for the contract
    ;
    WITH cteKillTreatment AS 
    (
        SELECT --*
            ks.PLANT_CODE,
            KS.KILL_DATE,
            KS.KILL_ORDER_NBR,
            c.CONTRACT_CODE,
            t.MEDICINE_TYPE,
            ISNULL(t.MEDICINE_TYPE, 'No Treatments') AS 'MedicineType',
            lkpTS.Severity
        FROM
            KILL_SCHEDULE ks
        INNER JOIN 
            contract c ON  ks.CONTRACT_CODE = c.CONTRACT_CODE
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            cont_disease cd ON  c.CONTRACT_CODE = cd.CONTRACT_CODE
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            treatment t ON  cd.TREATMENT_CODE = t.TREATMENT_CODE
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            @lkpTreatmentSeverity lkpTS ON  t.MEDICINE_TYPE = lkpTS.MedicineType
    )
    --Kill Schedule Treatment (1 record only; most severe medicine).
    SELECT
        @GetMostSevereTreatement = 
            CONCAT(cteKT.Severity, ': ', cteKT.MedicineType)  
        --    cteKT.*
        --    , subKT.CountMeds
        --    , subKT.CountDistinctMeds
    FROM
        cteKillTreatment cteKT
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT TOP 1 
             cte.PLANT_CODE,
             cte.KILL_DATE,
             cte.KILL_ORDER_NBR, 
             cte.CONTRACT_CODE,
             COUNT(*) CountMeds,
             COUNT(DISTINCT cte.MEDICINE_TYPE) AS CountDistinctMeds,
             MAX(cte.Severity) as TreatementMostSevere
         FROM
             cteKillTreatment cte
         GROUP BY
             cte.PLANT_CODE, cte.KILL_DATE, cte.KILL_ORDER_NBR, cte.CONTRACT_CODE
         HAVING
             MAX(cte.Severity) = cte.Severity
        ) subKT ON cteKT.CONTRACT_CODE = subKT.CONTRACT_CODE
                AND cteKT.KILL_DATE = subKT.KILL_DATE
                AND cteKT.KILL_ORDER_NBR = subKT.KILL_ORDER_NBR
    WHERE 
        cteKT.CONTRACT_CODE = @paramContractCode

    RETURN @GetMostSevereTreatement
END
GO
;
```

Comment: `RETURNS varchar(50)` is not valid for a stored procedure. They always return `int` and there is no syntax to change this.`CREATE PROCEDURE` should be `CREATE FUNCTION` and there is no `number` datatype

Comment: I updated the SQL with the `CREATE FUNCTION` syntax and changed the datatype to `numeric(5,0)`.  These changes resolved the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing up Stored procedure and Functions.You can return data from stored procedure using output variable or you can use return code. The return code will only return a integer value that is generally used as a status code. In your code , it looks like you would like to use Function rather then stored proc.

Please read below for better understanding -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

In a stored procedure the `RETURN` statement is used used to exit immediately and can only (optionally) return an integer expression that represents a status code. If no integer is specified, a value of 0 (success) is returned. To return a varchar(50) value,  your options are

1. Either you can use a scalar `FUNCTION` that returns a single value.
2. A stored procedure can set output parameters that are declared in the parameter list with the `OUT` keyword as follows:

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[udfGetKillContractTreatmentMostSevere] (@paramContractCode INT, @GetMostSevereTreatment VARCHAR(50) OUT)
   ```

Then you can simply set the value of the out parameter and it will be returned from the stored procedure. Note that a stored procedure can have multiple out parameters.

Comment: Yes you CAN use a return statement in a stored procedure, just not in the location and for the purpose OP intended.

Comment: This statement is not correct - "You cannot use a RETURN statement in a stored procedure." Please double check your theory.